# Local uploading image issue with Rails, Carrierwave & Minimagick; Image size must be <size> and it was 0x0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, carrierwave, minimagick

I am getting an error on Carrierwave image upload that used to be functional. I am trying to upload a 114x114 image, but upon upload I am seeing an error message that says:

```
Icon2x image size must be 114x114 and it was 0x0
```

The strangest part about this bug is that it is only occurring locally for me. We have an app in production that supports image upload that has always worked for me, but today it suddenly began throwing this error. However, my coworker reported that the upload function still works perfectly for her. **Weird.**

So every time I try to upload any image, regardless of size, production or dev I get this error. And no body else is getting it. For the love of my future children I cannot figure out what is going on here. Anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like very many people have run into this bug, but here is what worked for me.

I simply `brew update` and bingo was his name-o.